# Leaking memory in a queue

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, queue

I am having a memory leak with my Queue class. I used valgrind to locate the memory leak, and it is occurring on the same line both times. That line is marked in the code.

```
template <typename T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue(const T& x)
{

    if(isEmpty())
    {
        Queue<T>* temp = new Queue<T>();//THIS IS THE LEAKED MEMORY
        m_data = x;
        m_next = temp;
        temp->m_next = NULL;
        return;

    }


    Queue<T>* temp = this;

    while(temp->m_next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->m_next;
    }
    Queue<T>* node = new Queue<T>();
    temp->m_data = x;
    node->m_next = temp->m_next;
    temp->m_next = node;
    return;
}
```

The function `isEmpty()` is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
bool Queue<T>::isEmpty() const
{
    return (m_next==NULL);
}
```

Any ideas about this would be great.

Comment: You're allocating a new Queue<T> but never freeing it.  At least not in the code you've shown.

Comment: this is not me that downvoted: but you don't need this return at the end of void method

Comment: Every New should have a Delete to match it! Can you show us the matching Delete?

Comment: show the dequeue method also.

Answer (score 0):

```
Queue<T>* temp = new Queue<T>();//THIS IS THE LEAKED MEMORY
```

this is because you have to free a memory somewhere,via

`delete temp;`

and probably you don't do it. Not in this code that you've showed. So simply delete this when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error. It was elsewhere in the code. I actually found it almost immediately after posting this question. Thanks for the help.